# Swift: Creating an empty array

Tags: objective-c, swift-language

The following:

```
var emptyArray = [String]();
```

What do I need the parentheses () for? [String] says, that the array accepts strings only. But why do I have to put the () there?

Comment: Just a quick terminology note: "Brackets" are the rectangular things you put around the word `String`.  The round things afterward are *parentheses*, or just "parens" if you're being informal.

Comment: Thanks for that! That helps me using the right words. Do you know what the parentheses are for?

Comment: I'm not a Swift developer, but if I had to guess, I'd say it's probably "constructor notation": the `[String]` denotes a *type*: array of strings, but you're not trying to assign a type to `emptyArray`; you're trying to assign an instance of that type, which is where the parens come in.  (Note: if any actual Swift devs see this and I'm way off, bear in mind the above: I've never used Swift. Just making an educated guess here.)

Comment: I have actually no idea what you're talking about! You might be right but I don't understand some things like "constructor notation". I can't imagine what that is about. But that's probably because I'm German and English is not my mother tongue. So if you or someone else has another 'easier' explanation, give it to me! :-D

Comment: I reread it a few times and now I guess I understand what you were trying to say. If any swift developer could say whether that's true or not, that'd be great. :-)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: As an aside, parentheses, square brackets, and curly braces are generally referred to as round, square, and curly brackets outside the US, so it’s not wrong; however, American English is basically the lingua franca of computing.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I've always called the things on the left "square brackets" and the things on the right "brackets", but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things are true in Swift:

1. To instantiate an object of type `T` in Swift you write code `T()`.
2. The type "name" of an array of Strings is `[String]`

Combine the two and you get `[String]()`

Comment: So: `var emptyArray = [String]();` instantiates an object of the type emptyArray and emptyArray is a array of strings?

Comment: @S.Eberl No, the type is "array of String". I've never written Swift, but I doubt it has a type "empty array". So you're creating an object of type "array of String" which *happens to be empty*. The emptiness itself isn't part of the type.

Comment: Number 1 doesn't explain why that is, and number 2 doesn't elaborate much. Let me fill the holes: `T()` is a shorthand for `T.init()`. `[String]` is a shorthand for `Array<String>`. Thus, `[String]()` is a shorthand for `Array<String>.init()`